# How to optimize join between a small table and large table?

Tags: database, join

A small database (one machine n1) and a very large database(on machine n2, with billion records) need to be joined.
The app server would need to read the data from the db servers into memory.
Should it read the small db first ? and then read from the second db ?

How can this join be executed fastest ? 
How is this done in real life in general ?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should try to push the processing into the database. Maybe the big database server can pull the small one local and process everything on the server.

If you want to process in the application a common and usually optimal strategy is to perform a hash join. Convert the small data set into a hash table. Then, you can probe the items from the big data set against that hash table. This requires little memory, little CPU and you can stream the big data set.

This strategy always works if the join condition is equality (e.g. `Orders.CustomerID = Customers.ID`) and one of the two sets is small enough to fit in memory.